# mapping over the rows of a data frame

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame with columns c1, ..., cn, and a function f that takes in the columns of this data frame as arguments.
How can I apply f to each row of the data frame to get a new data frame?

For example,

```
x = data.frame(letter=c('a','b','c'), number=c(1,2,3))
# x is
# letter | number
#      a | 1
#      b | 2
#      c | 3

f = function(letter, number) { paste(letter, number, sep='') }

# desired output is
# a1
# b2
# c3
```

How do I do this? I'm guessing it's something along the lines of {s,l,t}apply(x, f), but I can't figure it out.

Comment: so in the end, there are no direct way to map over rows ? i cant believe it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

as @greg points out, paste() can do this. I suspect your example is a simplification of a more general problem. After struggling with this in the past, [as illustrated in this previous question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074606/doing-a-plyr-operation-on-every-row-of-a-data-frame-in-r) I ended up using the plyr package for this type of thing. plyr does a LOT more, but for these things it's easy:

```
> require(plyr)
> adply(x, 1, function(x) f(x$letter, x$number))
  X1 V1
1  1 a1
2  2 b2
3  3 c3
```

you'll want to rename the output columns, I'm sure

So while I was typing this, @joshua showed an alternative method using `ddply`. The difference in my example is that `adply` treats the input data frame as an array. `adply` does not use the "group by" variable `row` that @joshua created. How he did it is exactly how I was doing it until Hadley tipped me to the `adply()` approach. In the aforementioned question.

Comment: You could simplify this with `transform` or `summarize`:

`adply(x, 1, summarize, paste(letter, number, sep = ""))`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Yep, my example was just a toy example. I looked at plyr+reshape a while ago, and didn't understand it =(, but I'll definitely have to take a look again.

Comment: @JoFrhwld, you are exactly right about simplifying. The example Hadley gave me does exactly that. I didn't want to simplify too much, however, as I wanted a general answer that could be applied to other things.

Answer (score 7):

```
paste(x$letter, x$number, sep = "")
```

Comment: This is the way I would have done it! It's almost like we've been mentored by the same R master ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you were thinking of something like this, but note that the `apply` family of functions do not return data.frames.  They will also attempt to coerce your data.frame to a matrix before applying the function.

```
apply(x,1,function(x) paste(x,collapse=""))
```

So you may be more interested in `ddply` from the `plyr` package.

```
> x$row <- 1:NROW(x)
> ddply(x, "row", function(df) paste(df[[1]],df[[2]],sep=""))
  row V1
1   1 a1
2   2 b2
3   3 c3
```