# How to avoid implicit character conversion when using apply on dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

When using `apply` on a data.frame, the arguments are (implicitly) converted to character. An example:

```
df <- data.frame(v=1:10, t=1:10)
df <- transform(df, t2 = as.POSIXlt(t, origin = "2013-08-13"))
class(df$t2[1])
## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" (correct)
```

but:

```
 apply(df, 1, function(y) class(y["t2"]))
 ## [1] "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
 ## [7] "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

Is there any way to avoid this conversion? Or do I always have to convert back through `as.POSIXlt(y["t2"])`?

**edit**
My df has 2 timestamps (say, t2 and t3) and some other fields (say, v1, v2). For each row with given t2, I want to find k (e.g. 3) rows with t3 closest to, but lower than t2 (and the same v1), and return a statistics over v2 from these rows (e.g. an average). I wrote a function f(t2, v1, df) and just wanted to apply it on all rows using `apply(df, 1, function(x) f(y["t2"], y["v1"], df)`. Is there any better way to do such things in R?

Comment: The real answer here is that you shouldn't use `apply` on a data frame. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The *conversion* is occurring because your `data.frame` is being coerced to a  `matrix`.

Comment: Per your edits you really have two different questions (IMO).  I'd say ask the second question (Your Edit) with an appropriate data set, what you've tried and your desired output.

Comment: I often need to step through the rows of a data frame and `apply` comes to mind as a simple way to grab a row and access the columns. E.g. "take column 1 and column 4 from each row and do something with them".  Is there a better way to achieve this? Is using `apply` considered inherently bad practise and if so why?

Comment: After rephrasing by @SlowLearner (thanks) I realized my original problem is answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074606/doing-a-plyr-operation-on-every-row-of-a-data-frame-in-r

Comment: I use `strtoi` to convert characters back to numbers.

Comment: This is truly disgusting default behaviour

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's wrap up multiple comments into an explanation.

1. the use of `apply` converts a `data.frame` to a `matrix`.  This
   means that the least restrictive class will be used.  The least
   restrictive in this case is character.
2. You're supplying `1` to `apply`'s `MARGIN` argument.  This applies 
   by row and makes you even worse off as you're really mixing classes 
   together now.  In this scenario you're using `apply` designed for matrices 
   and data.frames on a vector.  This is not the right tool for the job.
3. In ths case I'd use `lapply` or `sapply` as rmk points out to grab the classes of
   the single t2 column as seen below:

Code:

```
df <- data.frame(v=1:10, t=1:10)
df <- transform(df, t2 = as.POSIXlt(t, origin = "2013-08-13"))

sapply(df[, "t2"], class)
lapply(df[, "t2"], class)

## [[1]]
## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
## 
## .
## .
## . 
## 
## [[9]]
## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
## 
## [[10]]
## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

In general you choose the `apply` family that fits the job.  Often I personally use `lapply` or a `for` loop to act on specific columns or subset the columns I want using indexing (`[, ]`) and then proceed with `apply`.  The answer to this problem really boils down to determining what you want to accomplish, asking is `apply` the most appropriate tool, and proceed from there.

May I offer this [blog post](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/) as an excellent tutorial on what the different `apply` family of functions do.

Comment: The blog post is excellent, but I think it does not solve my problem. `by` should be used for data frames, but I need more than just grouping by v1.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sapply(df, function(y) class(y["t2"]))

$v
[1] "integer"

$t
[1] "integer"

$t2
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to apply my function to each row of the data frame. As a result, I want as many rows as in the original data frame.

Comment: In that case, you could use purrrlyr::by_row